# What is the main difference between `JMP EBX` and `JMP DWORD PTR DS:[EBX]`?

Tags: assembly, x86

I am trying to pass a parameter to `EIP` register as a jump instruction to `EBX` register.

Answer (score 5):

## Short answer

`JMP EBX` will jump to the address stored in the `EBX` register within the current code segment.`JMP DWORD PTR DS:[EBX]` will jump to the address stored at memory offset `EBX`  within the code segment that is pointed to by `DS`.

For example, let `DS` = **0x0440**, `EBX` = **0x00006200**, and the first four bytes of memory at address **0x00006200** be **0x00003500** (which would be stored as **00 35 00 00** on a little-endian machine).
`JMP EBX` becomes `JMP 0x00006200`.
`JMP DWORD PTR DS:[EBX]` becomes `JMP 0x0440:0x00003500`

## Long answer

`JMP EBX` has the following signature:

```
JMP r/m32
```

In this case, the jump address is stored either in a 32-bit register (your case) or as a 32-bit variable in memory. The processor performs a **near jump** (in the same code segment), at the address specified by the operand, by loading the value into `EIP`.

`JMP DWORD PTR DS:[EBX]`, on the other hand, has the following signature:

```
JMP ptr16:32
```

Here the jump address is supplied in two pieces. The first value (before the colon) gives the address of the code segment to jump to, and the second (after the colon) gives the offset within that code segment. The jump may be to a different code segment than the current and is thus a **far jump**. The processor performs the jump by loading the first
value into `CS` and the second into `EIP`.
In addition, the second instruction uses `[EBX]`, as opposed to `EBX` in the first. That means it will read the memory at the offset stored in `EBX` and use that value.
`DWORD PTR` is a **size directive** that tells the assembler the memory should be treated as a 32-bit integer.

[Here](http://sandsprite.com/CodeStuff/Understanding_imports.html) is an example of the second jump in use.

Comment: That's not `jmp ptr16:32`.  That's `jmp r/m32` with a memory operand using the default segment (`DS`), which the OP's disassembler puts in explicitly to clutter the output and make it harder to read.

Answer (score 4):

`JMP EBX` means to instructs the CPU to jump to address pointed by `EBX` register value. If `EBX` is `12345678h`, it'll jump to address `12345678h`. So the instruction is interpreted as `JMP 12345678h`.

`JMP DWORD PTR DS:[EBX]` means to instructs the CPU to jump to address pointed by a `DWORD` value read from a memory address pointed by `EBX` register value and the `DS` selector. If `EBX` is `11111111h`, the CPU will read the `DWORD` value from memory at address `DS:11111111h`, then jump to the address pointed by that `DWORD` value (the value from the memory). If the `DWORD` value from the memory is `22222222h`, it'll jump to address `22222222h`. So the instruction is interpreted as `JMP DWORD PTR DS:[11111111h]`. After the memory is read, it would be interpreted as `JMP 22222222h`.